# Serverless: Service files not changed. Skipping deployment

Tags: deployment, serverless-framework

After some successful projects, I have deleted the functions inside AWS-lambda, deleted the logs in CloudWatch and the IAM roles.
Also deleted the `my-service` folder from my Documents.

Then I followed the steps in this [tutorial](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/) in serverless.

Now when I run:

```
serverless deploy --aws-profile testUser_atWork
```

where testUser_atWork is one of my profiles to connect in AWS.

I get the follow error:

```
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Service files not changed. Skipping deployment...
Service Information
service: my-service
stage: dev
region: us-east-1
stack: my-service-dev
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  None
functions:
  hello: my-service-dev-hello




//serverless.yml

service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10


functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
```

And this my handler.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      input: event,
    }),
  };

  callback(null, response);

  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // callback(null, { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event });
};
```

I don't understand why it is skipping deployment.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

have you tried : 
`serverless deploy --aws-profile testUser_atWork --force`   to force it to update the stack?

Otherwise, try deleting the stack in cloudformation, or with the `serverless remove` command

Comment: Yes the key was the cloudformation. I had to delete everything from there to be updated with the new functions, or to create a new service name.